# batch training with One-Class SVM model

Tags: python, anomaly-detection

i am working with an anomaly detection problem.
i have a large dataset that i cannot fully load  it in the memory does batch training works with normal ML models ?

does this make sense ????

```
# Initialize the One-Class SVM model
one_class_svm = OneClassSVM(nu=nu, kernel=kernel, gamma=gamma)

# Training in batches
batch_size = 1000

    for batch_data in batch_generator(X, batch_size):
        # Train the one-class SVM on the current batch
        one_class_svm.fit(batch_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this solved my problem with partial fit
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDOneClassSVM.html